# Solving coefficients of a function having boundary conditions

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have a function `F=c+dz`, which has particular boundary values, say `F(z=1)=2` and `F(z=-1)=1`, Then I can determine the coefficients: `c=1.5` and `d=0.5`. However, the following does not work!

```
ClearAll; 
F[c_, d_, z_] = c + d*z;
Print[F[c, d, 1]]; Print[F[c, d, -1]];
Solve[{F[c, d, 1] == 2, F[c, d, -1] == 1}, {c, d}];
Print["c=", c, " d=", d];
```

Where's the mistake?

PS. There's a question of similar title [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45219/finding-undetermined-coefficients-with-boundary-conditions), which hasn't received an answer (and looks complicated too).

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand how to define a function and how replacement rules work. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193) is a nice start point.

```
f[c_, d_, z_] := c + d z
s = Solve[{f[c, d, 1] == 2, f[c, d, -1] == 1}, {c, d}]

(* {{c -> 3/2, d -> 1/2}} *)

Print["c=", c /. s[[1]], " d=", d /. s[[1]]]

(* c=3/2 d=1/2 *)
```

Comment: What if I just use `s = Solve[{f[c, d, 1] == 2, f[c, d, -1] == 1}]` in the second line (omitting `{c,d}` part)? Seems that works too. Anyway still `c` and `d` don't take their values (What is `Print[c,d];`?). How does `s` become an array?

Comment: @hbaromega `Solve[]` doesn't return "values" but "replacement rules". Please read the docs and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/193)

Comment: Thanks. I have read this. Still it's not clear what's the point of mentioning `c` and `d`, if `Solve` cannot return them! Anyway, granting that, could you explain me how it stores in an array `s`? Say, what would `s[[2]]` mean and when can I use that?

Comment: @hbaromega http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/193

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @belisarius' solution, you might want to look at `StringForm`

```
Clear[f]

f[c_, d_, z_] = c + d z; (* either Set or SetDelayed works *)

s = Solve[{f[c, d, 1] == 2, f[c, d, -1] == 1}, {c, d}];

StringForm["c = `1`, d = `2`", c, d] /. s[[1]]
```

[image]